# "Та, мимо которой они проходили". Одним словом.

Tags: общие-вопросы

Мне кажется, минуемой. Например: "он уставился на минуемый дом". Или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глагол "миновать" при обозначении движения выражает смысл "ухода" от чего-то (в этом значении есть явный оттенок однократности), поэтому образованному от него причастию не придать "растянутого во времени" смысла. 
"Встретившаяся им по пути постройка оказалась длинной: они долго проходили мимо неё, пока не миновали, наконец."

Answer (score 0):

Для начала: у вас что-то с падежами и вообще с грамматикой напутано. 
Если "та, мимо которой" то уж "минуем**ая**". И это она.
А дом - он.

В отношении самого слова "минуемый". Оно понятно, но не нормативно. Использовать не рекомендуется. Разве как окказионализм.

Найти нужное слово вряд ли удастся. "проходимый" (по образцу "проезжаемый") занято другим значением, а точных нормативных синонимов что-то не вспоминается...

Answer (score 0):

Если непременно с этим словом, то не в настоящем времени и, естественно, не в будущем: Мы миновали ту, которая... Мы не миновали авторской правки вопроса...

Дом "миновать" не может, ибо статичен, если не на колёсах.